# Tight border on current matlab figure

Tags: matlab, border, figure

I know

> imshow('myimage.png','border','tight');

will give a tight border around the image. But what if I already have an image open? Is there a way to make it have a tight border?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Select the axis of the figure where the image is shown, by clicking over the image.

(2) Type on the Command Window

> > axis tight

assuming that this is what you wish to do...  It was not clear from your question what you exactly wanted to do.

Answer (score 8):

```
imshow('coins.png')
set(gca, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0 0 1 1])
```